# Commenting clfinish() out makes program %100 faster

Tags: opencl

I have an opencl kernel batch class that enqueues more than 40 kernels and there is a clFinish() between each kernel execution.

**Question:** When I comment out the clFinish()s then program runs %100 faster, does this mean there are undefined behaviours between kernels when they use same buffers to write and read? I suspect performance increase comes from better utilisation of resources of gpu/occupation. Does using an **in-order command queue** guarantee a barrier between two kernels or do I need a clFinish() between them?

Its a simple physics model and no differency is visible between two versions.

Maybe I just need to use clFinish() at the end?

**Edit:** This command queue is not using CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE.

Comment: can you post some of the host code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to use `clFinish` inbetween kernel calls if all kernel calls execute on the same command queue and this is an in-order queue, which is exactly your scenario so you don't need all those `clFinish` calls, just keep the last one.

The performance difference comes from a combination of the following:

- There is overhead in each `clFinish` call to send all queued commands to the device and check their execution status.
- These `clFinish` calls also create breaks in the work being done by the GPU - the GPU has to wait for the next kernel to be enqueued and sent to the device after `clFinish`.  Omitting the calls to `clFinish` means that kernel calls get sent to the GPU while previous kernels are still executing.

Comment: Yes, all are in same queue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the kernel isn't being run?  Enqueuing a kernel is cheap and doesn't require any effort on the part of the host.  However, calling clEnqeueNDRangeKernel != Running the kernel.

```
//Start host timer
clEnqueNDRangeKernel(...);
//Stop host timer - this doesn't actually time the kernel on the host
```

vs.

```
//Start host timer
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(...);
clFinish();
//Stop host timer - this does time the kernel on the host
```

Alternatively, you can use kernel profiling and events.

Comment: Absolutely valid point, every single OpenCL function call's error status needs to be checked, e.g. kernel execution errors might only manifest as an error code returned by a later `clFinish`.